# Is there a way to programmatically disable the touchpad drivers in linux (wayland)?

Tags: c, linux, driver, mouse, wayland

I am trying to disable the ELAN touchpad driver in linux wayland (mutter) in order to have my own program send ioctl's and have full control over this device. My program reads from `/dev/input/eventX`.

I have tried both disabling `send-events` in gnome dconf editor and grabbing the device like so: `ioctl(touchpad_fd, EVIOCGRAB, 1)` but the former let's the touchpad behave normally and doesn't exclusively make it respond to my program, and the latter causes the mouse to freeze when the program is being run and bug out after it is stopped.

The point of the program is to move the mouse in an absolute manner in response to eventX, but having the normal function of the touchpad move it as well breaks this function as it becomes a mix of the two (not quite absolute or relative).

The gist is available here: https://gist.github.com/ElijaRock/fe12acccb24a2ce8eb14d8b4fbc61197

Is there a way to do this at a lower level than gsettings? Cheers.

Comment: This may not help you, like at all, but under X I do `synclient TouchpadOff=1`.  Maybe it's worth running that under strace to see what it does?